# 2 consecutive redirects with chance to go back

Tags: php, redirect

i'm trying to do this:

PAGE A: Has a button to a preview.

When it's pressed, the user must see PAGE C, but when the user hits back button in PAGE C, it must go to  PAGE B.

So, what i've done is to redirect from A to B with a url parameter, so at the beginning of B, it redirects to C.

The problem is when i go back, the url has the same parameter, so the redirect from B to C is done again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use session variables, where are your users, and based on that, you can redirect to the proper place.

Comment: you can alter backbutton behaviour with javascript... i think this is gonna solve it quicker than using parameters...

Comment: @RichardBernards this question was not tagged with `javascript`.

Comment: @lolka_bolka that doesnt mean it shouldnt be mentioned in the comments ;)

Comment: The session variable works good, but i dont have the url in the browser history. When i hit back, it goes to PAGE A

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Page A:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['visited']))
{
 echo "<a href='C.php'>To page C</a>";
 $_SESSION['visited']=1;
}
else
{
 header('Location: B.php');
}
?>
```

Page B:

```
<?php
session_start();

 echo "Page B";
?>
```

Page C:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "Page C";
?>
```